# ASP.NET scenario Interview question. How would you answer it?

Tags: asp.net

Here's the question scenario:

Suppose you have a multiple-page ASP.NET web site with the following
requirements:

1. User-specific data for the currently logged in user is loaded and is required on each individual page of the application during a user's session.
2. The application itself only allows a certain number of users to be logged in at one time.
3. The next time a specific user logs in, the user should be returned to the last page visited.

Given this information, briefly describe how you would use ASP.NET to manage the state of the application to meet these needs?

Here's my thoughts and reasons. Please provide yours.

> User-specific data for the currently
>   logged in user is loaded and is
>   required on each individual page of
>   the application during a user's
>   session.

This is suggesting to me that the interviewer is looking to see if I would suggest using Master pages as a way to provide a common approach to displaying the same thing on every page.

> The application itself only allows a
>   certain number of users to be logged
>   in at one time.

Could the sought response be that, because scaling isn't an issue due to the limited number of users, that it is OK to put this information in the Session object for performance reasons or is this a trap and some of approach is better?

> The next time a specific user logs in,
>   the user should be returned to the
>   last page visited

A cookie seems the best approach to track the last page access, since this doesn't seem to be critical information.

Please tell me how you would handle these question if you wanted to make the best impression

Feel free to provide input or comment an any line item.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi all if the above mentioned scenario needs to be done in Asp.Net MVC ..How should it be done. Can u please explain .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my thoughts:

1. They might be looking for Master Pages, but my first thought here was whether you're going to cache this user data, so you're not making a database query every time they hit a new page. To really impress them, you might mention partial caching techniques so that the repetitive portions of the page don't even need to be re-rendered with each page load.
2. I think you're right: they're helping you to conclude that the session state is an appropriate place to cache the user data. Just be sure you ask the appropriate questions, like "How many users?", and "How much data per user?"
3. The cached data could be used to keep track of the last-requested page, and when the user's session expires, you could save this data into a database table to be retrieved next time they log in.

That third item is awfully tricky. What if the user was last looking at an object that has since been deleted? What would be the intended behavior if a user logged in from one computer, did some work, and then logged in simultaneously from another computer or browser? I'd be sure to ask these kinds of questions, not least to show that I understand the implications of a requirement like this. If their responses lead you to believe that they're looking for a simple solution, go with the simple solution. Otherwise, tweak your response to be only as complicated as necessary.

Answer (score 4):

As far as (3) is concerned, consider a shared PC.   User A logs into a website using their site based user name/password.  Does a whole load of work and shuts down the browser.   USer B then comes along and on the same PC logs into the same site using their details.  However, they will get the cookie from User A and be redirected to the last page they saw.   This happens because Cookies are tied to the browser / OS user, where as you are potentially applying the site security separately in the application.

In this situation you would either need to put the user name into the cookie (encrypted) or use a server side method to store the location

Comment: Likewise, if the same user logged in from two different PCs, they wouldn't be put on the same page they last used.

Answer (score 1):

Just a small thought.. If the system are running in a "Farmed" environment the Session data can be cleared and need to be handled some way.

http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Store-Session-State-Server.aspx